# Apply multiple cellClass on ag-grid column

Tags: css, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to apply multiple cell classes on ag-grid (*community edition*) cell. I want to change cell background and set cell font to monospace. I have defined two *columnTypes*: **tomatoBackground** and **monospaceFont**. Next, I set table column "type" property providing both *columnTypes*.

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        headerName: "Athlete",
        field: "athlete"
    },
    {
        headerName: "Sport",
        field: "sport"
    },
    {
        headerName: "Age",
        field: "age",
        type: ["tomatoBackground", "monospaceFont"]
    }
]

columnTypes: {
    tomatoBackground: {
        cellClass: "ag-cell--tomato-background"
    },
    monospaceFont: {
        cellClass: "ag-cell--monospace-font"
    }
}
```

CSS code:

```
.ag-cell {
   &--tomato-background {
      background-color: tomato;
   }

   &--monospace-font {
      font-family: monospace, 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   }
}
```

Unfortunatly, only the last one **cellClass** is actually applied on "Age" column (*in this case it is **monospaceFont***).
Creating a single CSS class that has both CSS properties (*tomato background* and *monospace font*) is not an option for me.

Could anyone help to solve the problem? Is it even possible? An example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify more than 1 type, ag-grid will override the properties, not combine them together. So what you could do is specify an array in the cellClass property directly on the column.

```
{
    headerName: "Age",
    field: "age",
    cellClass: ["ag-cell--tomato-background", "ag-cell--monospace-font"]
}
```

See the following documentation on cellClass:
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-styles/#cell-class

Comment: Not exactly the outcome I was hoping to get but solution is good enough. Thank you Matt!

Comment: can the columnDef be accessed and updated using gridApi?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like leveraging the `cellClassRules` property instead of the `cellClass` property allows you to combine columnType CSS classes.

```
columnTypes: {
    tomatoBackground: {
        cellClassRules: {
            "ag-cell--tomato-background": (params) => {
                return true;
            }
        }
    },
    monospaceFont: {
        cellClassRules: {
            "ag-cell--monospace-font": (params) => {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```